# Writing Sorted Table Data to the Table in a Separate Format using Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I'm relatively new to javascript and definitely new to google scripting.

I have a tab where raw data entry happens. I have another tab where that data is sorted, and an approval date is written next to that line later. I want that date to reflect back to the first tab in the proper line, and I also want to make sure that it stays on the proper line in the second tab (even after new lines are added and sorted in).

Attached is an example sheet with only a few lines. In reality I have more columns but they are irrelevant here.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14dh0IW7vO8c2OLc2O8WE-Ptuh3MJfLWTESVMA_DpOv0/edit?usp=sharing
My second tab uses the sheets SORT function. When A date is typed though, it creates an error. I was going to account for this by using onEdit() function and writing the date into the correct line in the first tab, then clearing the date column in the second tab (to avoid the error and keep it aligned).

```
''javascript
function onEdit() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName("check released");
  var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("Log");

  var job2 = sheet2.getRange("A2:A1000").getValues();
  var job1 = sheet1.getRange("A2:A1000").getValues();

  var draw2 = sheet2.getRange("B2:B1000").getValues();
  var draw1 = sheet1.getRange("B2:B1000").getValues();

  var inv2 = sheet2.getRange("C2:C1000").getValues();
  var inv1 = sheet1.getRange("C2:C1000").getValues();

  var dates2 = sheet2.getRange("D2:D1000");
  var dates_values = sheet2.getRange("D2:D1000").getValues();
  var dates1 = sheet1.getRange("D2:D1000");

  var indices = []

  var to_paste = []

  for(var i = 0; i < job2.length; i++) {
    var job2_Value = job2[i][0];
    var draw2_Value = draw2[i][0];
    var inv2_Value = inv2[i][0];
    for(var j=0; j<job2.length; j++) {
      var job1_Value = job1[j][0];
      var draw1_Value = draw1[j][0];
      var inv1_Value = inv1[j][0];
      if((job2_Value != "") && (job1_Value == job2_Value) && (draw1_Value === draw2_Value) && (inv1_Value === inv2_Value)) {
        indices.push([i]); 
      }
    }
  }  

  for(k in indices) {
    to_paste.push([dates2[k]])
  }

  Logger.log(to_paste)
  dates1.setValues(to_paste)
  dates2.clearContent()
  Logger.log("Cleared on check released page")

};
'''
```

This is the code that I've written, but it doesn't work and I don't know why. I also don't know where to find the console log.

Comment: Can I ask you about your question? 1. What is your issue? 2. Can you provide the detail information about `it doesn't work`? 3. Can you provide the output you expect?

Comment: When you answer the question from @Tanaike about "it doesn't work", if the problem is the the script fails, please copy/paste the Execution transcript into your question.

Comment: The issue is not that the script fails, but the actual algorithms are incorrect I think. I want indices to contain the indices of dates2 that correlate with the same record as dates1 should. Then to_paste should have the content from dates2 at the index from indices, and then to_paste should be written to dates2.

Comment: The link is to the google sheets example.

Comment: @Tedinoz any suggestions?

Comment: @Tanaike any suggestions?

Comment: May I clarify; please correct if I'm wrong. Two sheets i) "Log" and ii) "check released". "Log" contains information about work; there are three columns A ("Job#"-not unique), B ("Draw#"-not unique), and C ("Invoice#"-which _appears_ - but may not be - unique). A fourth column D ("Date") is intended to be updated via a script from sheet "check released". "check released" displays the data from "Log" by using a `sort` on all 4 columns of "Log". The objective is to enter a date in "Date" on "check released" and have it updated to the data on "Log".

Comment: FYI-View the log from the Script editor (View>Logs; also CTRL+Enter); view the Execution transcript from the Script editor (View>Execution transcript). There are other options to view and manage logs, but these are the ones that I personally use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a sheet "check released" that takes values from "sheet "Log". Your aim is enter a "release date" on "check released" and have that updated to "Log", and then reflected in "check released". The approach you took was to edit the actual linked "release date" value on "check released". Not surprisingly this wasn't successful because it was merely taking date from "Log".

In the following code:

- I have used a helper column on "check released" where the date can be entered.
- The onEdit(e) script detects the new value, finds the equivalent row on "Log".
- The script updates the "Date" column on "Log" - at this point, the values on "check released" are automatically updated.
- Then the script deletes the value in the helper column.

**Matching from "Log" to "check released"**

The matching of rows from "check released" to "Log" relies on several elements:

1. No record has a truly unique identifier.
2. However, the values of Job, Draw and Invoice numbers, when each is converted to a string and concatenated, generate a unique value that can be used to compare values from "Log" to "check released".
3. The values on "Log" are processed in a loop to create a 1D array of concatenated values.
4. Event objects provide the edited Row on "check released"; and the Job, Draw and Invoice values in that row are concatenated.
5. Using the Javascript [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) method, the script 'finds' the row on "Log" that matches the unique concatenated value from the edited row.

Other items to note:

- the actual size of the data range on "Log" and "check released" is determined by using `getlastRow()`
- `getRange` and `getValues` are run once each for "Log" and "check released"
- Meaningful names for variables have been chosen to reflect their purpose; this assists in reading and understanding the code.

---

```
function onEdit(e) {
  // 5824330602
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var logsheet = "Log";
  var log = ss.getSheetByName(logsheet);
  var checkrsheet = "check released";
  var checkr = ss.getSheetByName(checkrsheet);


  // get Log data
  var logFR = 2;
  var logLR = log.getLastRow();
  var logLC = 4;
  var logRange = log.getRange(logFR,1,logLR-logFR+1,logLC);
  // Logger.log(logRange.getA1Notation());// DEBUG
  var logValues = logRange.getValues();


  // get check released data
  var checkrRange = checkr.getRange(logFR,1,logLR-logFR+1,logLC);
  //Logger.log(checkrRange.getA1Notation());
  var checkrValues = checkrRange.getValues();


  // build array of uniquelogitems
  var logitems=[];
  for (var i=0; i<logValues.length; i++) {
    var logjob = logValues[i][0].toString();
    var logdraw = logValues[i][1].toString();
    var loginv = logValues[i][2].toString();
    var logid = logjob+logdraw+loginv;
    //Logger.log("DEBUG: LOG: Job= "+logjob);
    //Logger.log("DEBUG: LOG: draw= "+logdraw);
    //Logger.log("DEBUG: LOG: inv= "+loginv);
    //Logger.log("DEBUG: LOG: concat= "+logid);
    var logid = logjob+logdraw+loginv;
    logitems.push(logid);
  }
  //Logger.log(logitems); //DEBUG


  // get the event objects
  var editedRow = e.range.getRow();
  var editedCol = e.range.getColumn();
  var editedSheet = e.range.getSheet().getSheetName();
  var editedValue = e.value;
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: row = "+editedRow+", column = "+editedCol+", Sheet = "+editedSheet)


  // apply logic to test whether this edit should be processed
  // Column 5 ("E") is the helper column
  if(editedRow >= logFR && editedRow <=logLR && editedCol === 5 && editedSheet === checkrsheet){
    // the edit is in Column E (Date), between the first and last rows of data, on the "check released" sheet
    //Logger.log("DEBUG: edit is OK. edit row = "+editedRow+". Keep processing");

    var checkrjob = checkrValues[editedRow-2][0].toString();
    var checkrdraw = checkrValues[editedRow-2][1].toString();
    var checkrinv = checkrValues[editedRow-2][2].toString();
    var checkritem = checkrjob+checkrdraw+checkrinv;
    //Logger.log("DEBUG: Checkr: job="+checkrjob+", draw= "+checkrdraw+", inv = "+checkrinv+", Item = "+checkritem);
    var match = logitems.indexOf(checkritem);
    //Logger.log("DEBUG: Matching row = "+match);

    // get the existing date
    var existingdate = logValues[+match+1][3];
    var cell = log.getRange(+match+2,4);
    //Logger.log("DEBUG: the update cell = "+cell.getA1Notation())


    // date field is a date, so update new date
    cell.setValue(editedValue);
    cell.setNumberFormat('mm/dd/yy');
    e.range.clearContent();

    //Logger.log("DEBUG: updated date on Log")
  }
  else{
    // the edit didn't meet the rule
    //Logger.log("DEBUG: edit did NOT meet criteria. Do not proceed")
  }

};
```

---

**Column E - Helper Column**

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Thank you! This looks to work really well! Is there a way to use only one column instead of the helper column also? Like if the sheet doesn't calculate after the edit and the query stays in tact. Is that possible? Otherwise this will work.

Comment: No. tl;dr You describe correlating records, pasting content to dates1, and "writing" back to dates2. That's a flawed understanding of dates2. Cell A1 of data2 contains a `sort` function and outputs to Columns A, B, C **AND** D. If the user types a date directly into a cell in Column D, `#REF!` is displayed in cell A1 and all the output cells of become blank. `onEdit` records the new date but there is no information to correlate. The helper column is essential (at least in my experience). On reflection, the green background should be on the helper column, not Column D.

Comment: Ok, I have implemented this into my full spreadsheet and it works fantastically. Thanks again!